# How can i resolve a parse error in scss loading in react with webpack?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-style-loader

Here's my super simple scss file:

```
html {
  body {
    font-size: 100%;
    background: url(../img/repeater.jpg);
  }
}
```

I'm importing it into my App.jsx file this way: `import "./App.scss";`

This is what's in my module:loaders:

```
            // SASS
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                include: /shared/,
                loaders: [
                    'style',
                    'css',
                    'autoprefixer?browsers=last 3 versions',
                    'sass?outputStyle=expanded'
                ]
            }
```

But, instead of awesome things happening I get this in my console:

```
SyntaxError: /Users/jasonshultz/Projects/work/gradebook/shared/containers/App/App.scss: Unexpected token (1:5)
> 1 | html {
    |      ^
  2 |   body {
  3 |     font-size: 100%;
  4 |     background: url(../img/repeater.jpg);
    at Parser.pp.raise (/Users/jasonshultz/Projects/work/gradebook/node_modules/babel-core/node_modules/babylon/index.js:1425:13)
    at Parser.pp.unexpected (/Users/jasonshultz/Projects/work/gradebook/node_modules/babel-core/node_modules/babylon/index.js:2907:8)
    at Parser.pp.semicolon (/Users/jasonshultz/Projects/work/gradebook/node_modules/babel-core/node_modules/babylon/index.js:2894:38)
    at Parser.pp.parseExpressionStatement (/Users/jasonshultz/Projects/work/gradebook/node_modules/babel-core/node_modules/babylon/index.js:2264:8)
    at Parser.parseExpressionStatement (/Users/jasonshultz/Projects/work/gradebook/node_modules/babel-core/node_modules/babylon/index.js:3596:20)
    at Parser.pp.parseStatement (/Users/jasonshultz/Projects/work/gradebook/node_modules/babel-core/node_modules/babylon/index.js:1955:17)
    at Parser.parseStatement (/Users/jasonshultz/Projects/work/gradebook/node_modules/babel-core/node_modules/babylon/index.js:3574:22)
    at Parser.pp.parseBlockBody (/Users/jasonshultz/Projects/work/gradebook/node_modules/babel-core/node_modules/babylon/index.js:2294:21)
    at Parser.pp.parseTopLevel (/Users/jasonshultz/Projects/work/gradebook/node_modules/babel-core/node_modules/babylon/index.js:1823:8)
    at Parser.parse (/Users/jasonshultz/Projects/work/gradebook/node_modules/babel-core/node_modules/babylon/index.js:1396:17)
```

Which is very unawesome. I threw the code up on github [here](https://github.com/jshultz/temp_project) if that helps. I've not had any luck so far getting it to work. I've tried different styles, etc. and nothing.

Comment: That log looks like babel is trying to process this file - are you sure it's not being parsed as JS?

Comment: this error happens because you are trying require `import routes                    from 'routes';` in `server.js` and in `routes` there is `scss` file but node can not process `scss` files.

Comment: @pherris: i'm not sure, it shouldn't be.

Comment: @Alexander: i don't see the scss references in the routes file? i looked in routes.jsx and don't see anything with an scss extension?

honestly, i'm not sure why server.js is importing the routes file anyway since it's also being used in client/index.jsx

Comment: @but in `routes.js` there is `containers/App/App` and in this file you include `import "./App.scss`

Comment: @Alexander ok I moved the file up  and into a css folder, still getting the same error, though.

Comment: do you have sass-loader and node-sass installed? ( npm install sass-loader node-sass webpack --save-dev )

Comment: @Mark: yes on both counts.

Comment: was this ever resolved? I'm having a very similar issue

Comment: @matthewalexander It might have, but I honestly don't remember. I went through a lot of trial and error with react back then. shortly after that, half our engineering team was laid off and I was one of them and this project got scrapped. I don't remember if it got fixed or how, unfortunately. Sorry. If I had a way of finding out or access to that repo I would have checked for you. :(